# Create a dataframe from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, reshape, create-table

I'd like to create a dataframe from a dataframe that created before. my first dataframe is:

```
    Sample motif chromosome
    1      CT-G.A    1
    1      TA-C.C    1
    1      TC-G.C    2
    2      CG-A.T    2
    2      CA-G.T    2
```

Then I want to create a dataframe like below, for all (96*24-motifs*chromosomes-):

```
    Sample CT-G.A,chr1 TA-C.C,chr1 TC-G.C,chr1 CG-A.T,ch1 CA-G.T,ch1 CT-G.A,chr2 TA-C.C,chr2 TC-G.C,chr2 CG-A.T,ch2 CA-G.T,ch2 
    1       1             1           0           0            0        0          0     1    0     0      0      0
    2       0             0           0           0            0        0          0     0    0     0      1      1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possble solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

We add a column `value` that indicates if a chromosome is present, then complete the `data.frame`, making sure we have rows for each `motif-chromosome-Sample` combination, where missing combinations get a `0` in the value column. We create a `key` out of the motif and chromosome columns, and then discard those columns. Lastly, we reshape the `data.frame` from long to wide (see [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/)) to get your desired format. Hope this helps!

---

```
df = read.table(text="Sample motif chromosome
1      CT-G.A    1
                1      TA-C.C    1
                1      TC-G.C    2
                2      CG-A.T    2
                2      CA-G.T    2
                2      CA-G.T    2",header=T)


library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df  %>% mutate(value=1) %>% complete(motif,chromosome,Sample,fill=list(value=0)) %>%
  mutate(key=paste0(motif,',chr',chromosome)) %>%
  group_by(Sample,key) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(value)) %>%
  spread(key,value) %>% 
  as.data.frame
```

Output:

```
  Sample CA-G.T,chr1 CA-G.T,chr2 CG-A.T,chr1 CG-A.T,chr2 CT-G.A,chr1 CT-G.A,chr2 TA-C.C,chr1 TA-C.C,chr2 TC-G.C,chr1 TC-G.C,chr2
1      1           0           0           0           0           1           0           1           0           0           1
2      2           0           2           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

Comment: I used it on my dataframe but it gives this error: "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows"

Comment: There are probably duplicates in your data. I added a duplicate row to your data and expanded the code to deal with those. Hope that solves it.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a classic case of when you would want to use `factor`s and ensure that the empty factor levels aren't dropped (which `dcast` and other functions might do unless explicitly told not to).

Using [@Florian's sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48607224/1270695), you can try:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("motif", "chromosome")
setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = cols][
  , dcast(unique(.SD)[, value := 1L], 
          Sample ~ motif + chromosome, value.var = "value", 
          fill = 0L, drop = FALSE)]
#   Sample CA-G.T_1 CA-G.T_2 CG-A.T_1 CG-A.T_2 CT-G.A_1 CT-G.A_2 TA-C.C_1 TA-C.C_2 TC-G.C_1 TC-G.C_2
# 1      1        0        0        0        0        1        0        1        0        0        1
# 2      2        0        1        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

I've moved "cols" and `myfun()` outside of the transformation to save some typing and make things look a little more tidy.

---

Using the "tidyverse", I'd take a slightly different approach from @Florian, perhaps something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate_at(c("motif", "chromosome"), factor) %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(key = interaction(motif, chromosome)) %>%
  select(-motif, -chromosome) %>%
  spread(key, value, fill = 0, drop = FALSE)
```

---

### Benchmarks

Benchmarks for these approaches and @Florian's can be found [at this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6b7b37db90037c114577f93ed391a022).

On 10,000 rows, and 20 resulting columns, the results look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you. I have used package `tidyr` and `dplyr`. Actually, I had preferred to use `unite` and `expand.grid` from `base r` to achieve by finally using `spread`

```
df <- read.table(text = "Sample motif chromosome
    1      CT-G.A    1
           1      TA-C.C    1
           1      TC-G.C    2
           2      CG-A.T    2
           2      CA-G.T    2", header = TRUE)

#add a column to represent presence of chromosome    
df$val <- 1
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#Complete missing rows
df_complete <- left_join(
          expand.grid(Sample=unique(df$Sample), motif=unique(df$motif), 
                         chromosome=unique(df$chromosome)),
             df, by = c("Sample", "motif", "chromosome"), copy = TRUE)

#Additional rows should have val = 0
df_complete$val[is.na(df_complete$val)] <- 0

df_complete %>%
    unite(motif, c("motif", "chromosome"), sep = ",chr" ) %>% 
    spread(motif, val)

#Result
  Sample CA-G.T,chr1 CA-G.T,chr2 CG-A.T,chr1 CG-A.T,chr2 CT-G.A,chr1 CT-G.A,chr2 TA-C.C,chr1 TA-C.C,chr2 TC-G.C,chr1 TC-G.C,chr2
1      1           0           0           0           0           1           0           1           0           0           1
2      2           0           1           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
```